# Combining Text in SwiftUI with a background property gives error as Cannot convert value of type 'some View' to expected argument type 'Text'?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
 Group{
                 Text("HI ")
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                    .background(Color.black)
                + Text("Hello again")
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
            }.padding()
```

I have this piece of code in SwiftUI and the combine `+` works as expected if I do not add the background property, after adding this I believe the view is not a Text anymore but a parent `View` so I cannot use combine `+` operator on two views, any easy solution to overcome this? I even tried creating custom modifier but they also convert the view into parent `View` and not `Text` so cannot use `+` as well, another solution I was trying was to create a custom UIKit plugin and convert to SwiftUI but that's too much work for this simple task, my main goal is to add a background in between my Texts in some highlighted texts.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `+` only for `Text`, `.background` modifier output is not `Text`, so you cannot use it.

The solution would be to use `HStack` instead

```
HStack(spacing: 0) {
    Text("HI ")
        .fontWeight(.heavy)
        .background(Color.black)
    Text("Hello again")
        .fontWeight(.heavy)
}.padding()
```

Comment: Thanks, HStack would make the text view not floatable, I mean when the view is displayed with varying width it will be not an optimized view as in case of Text where it floats with increasing height and multi-lines @asperi