# Combine text and shape into one line of text in SwiftUI?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, concatenation

Im trying to combine a simple text object with a shape inside of swiftUI. Or in a broader sense, I need to combine simple text object with something that allows a frame so that I can read that frames position using geometry reader.

I want something along the lines of

HStack{
Text("This is the first part of the question") +  Text("Missing word").frame() + Text("second part of the question)
}

and have the result just be one fluid multiline of text i.e.

This is the first part of the question missing word second part of question.

Is this possible in swiftUI or is there some kind of work around? Anything I am finding online to concatenate multiple Text() objects require that they all conform to Text. When I add a frame to the one, it returns a view and no longer conforms to any of those work arounds.

I found another post of someone looking to do the same thing that may offer better insight [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61426088/combining-text-in-swiftui-with-a-background-property-gives-error-as-cannot-conve)

[image]

Comment: If you are looking to highlight a section of the text then you could try ```AttributedString```, see also [Highlight a specific part of the text in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62111551/20386264). Otherwise, a frame has a rectangular shape with width and height, so how are you expecting it to behave when it contains text that wraps over the end of the line?

Comment: So I need to add either a .frame() attribute or I could also use .background() on the string so that I can read that position using geometry reader. The text that has this attribute will be a single word. I want to combine 3 separate string vales with the 2nd one having a .frame or .background attribute and then combine those 3 string and have it display on the view as if it is just 1 line of text.

Comment: A single word with a hyphen could still wrap, but maybe you can exclude that case. So once you have the position... what do you want to do with it, if you don't want to highlight it?

Comment: the end goal is to have a text view of a question like "This is a __________ question" and below that have a buttons with words [choice1] [choice2] [correct] [choice3]. When the user clicks the [correct] button I want the button to animate/move to the empty space in the question. So I need to know the x/y coords of the empty space in the question to tell the button to move there when it is clicked

Comment: If I could read the position of the text() itself I could do that but from what I can determine on my own, I need some view type to be able to read its coordinates so that's why I'm trying to incorporate either a .background to the text or .frame so I can read that position and tell the button to animate to that position

Comment: I would suggest breaking up the complete sentence into individual words (tokens) and then using a wrapping HStack to put it all back together - see [SwiftUI HStack with Wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58842453/20386264). Once you have that, a simpler way to achieve the animation effect might be to use ```.matchedGeometryEffect```.

Comment: I can definitely try that, thank you very much. I will update with my progress

Comment: I can suggest you just prepare some words for users answers and when they clicked on some button change your string value for Text. For example default value " __________ ". And then in your button action area use withAnimation { defaultValue = buttonValue }, also you can play with animations there. Or even go with transition and .id

Answer (score 0):

You can combine Text like this `Text("some text \(Text("text").foregroundColor(.black))")`

```
HStack{ 
    Text("This is the first part of the question \(Text("Missing word").frame()) \(Text("second part of the question))")
    }
```

Comment: Can you double check you syntax? Ive never combined text this way and when I I try to incorporate you're answer directly, I'm receiving an error that I have added tot he question above

Comment: I believe I fixed the syntax but I am getting the following error 'appendInterpolation' is unavailable: Unsupported type for interpolation, see LocalizedStringKey.StringInterpolation for supported types. I think its because it is has the .frame() attribute